# Can gravitation violate the law of conservation of energy? (Boils down to: Why is the force of gravity assigned a negative value?)

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, potential-energy

I guess it can't, but here is the idea:

Let's consider a massive object with mass $M$. Then we have another object with a way smaller mass $m$. Now, the smaller object is a distance $r$ away. The gravitational pull between the two objects will be equal to $g=G\frac {mM} {r^2}$ and therefore the potential energy of the smaller object will be equal to $E_{pot}=mG\frac {mM} {r^2}r=G\frac {m^2M} r$. Now let's look at what happens when we double our radius:$E_{pot}=G\frac {m^2M} {2r}$. We can see that by doubling our radius, we just halfed the potential energy.

When our smaller object, starting at $h=2r$ is now being pulled towards the bigger object, we can see that its kinetic energy increases (since it's going faster) but it's potential energy must also increase, since it is approaching double its starting potential energy.

Where is the error in this argumentation? Where does the gained energy come from?

---

Edit: I made a kind of obvious error in my calculations when calculating $g$ - obviously, I was calculating Force $F$ and not the actual acceleration $g$. Since $F=ma$ and $\frac Fm = a$, the correct thing to get would have been $E_{pot}=mG\frac {mM} {mr^2}r=G\frac {mM} r$. This still doesn't solve my original question though, since to solve the apparent paradox, the result should have a negative sign in front.

Comment: When you raise a mass in a gravitational field, you increase it's potential energy

Comment: Actually, I just showed that that isn't the case.

Comment: Aside from the below answers, I would say the issue with your extra mass terms comes from when you say $g=G\frac{mM}{r^2}$, however this isn't true and you are using the symbol commonly used for acceleration (g), instead of the more commonly accepted letter for force (F). Thus when you attempt to calculate the potential energy you are actually incorrectly writing $E=m F r$ which is not the expression for potential energy.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's one important thing I got wrong! Going to edit the question now!

Comment: @Smiley1000 If you put extra work into lifting an object higher, then you get extra work out of it when it drops. If you find any other answer your formula is incorrect.

Comment: Well, that's exactly why I asked where the error in my argumentation was. You didn't contribute anything by stating how we experience gravity to work - I know that very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a sign error.  The potential energy for gravitation is *lower* the closer two objects are to each other, not higher.  The potential energy of two objects separated by $r$ is

$$U = U_0 -\frac{GM_1 M_2}{r}$$

where $U_0$ is the potential energy at infinite separation.  $U_0$ is conventionally taken to be zero, but it doesn't really matter what value it has.

---

### Potential energy from Newton's law

The way to work out the potential energy is to remember that work is the integral of force over distance.  So if you consider two objects as above, then you have

$$F(r) = -\frac{GM_1M_2}{r^2} \quad\text{Newton's law}$$

And now consider moving one of the bodies from $r=\infty$ in to some finite value to get the potential energy:

$$
\begin{aligned}
 U(r) &= \int\limits_\infty^r -F(\rho)\,d\rho\\
      &= GM_1M_2\int\limits_\infty^r \frac{1}{\rho^2}\,d\rho\\
      &= GM_1M_2\left[-\frac{1}{\rho}\right]_{\rho=\infty}^{\rho=r}\\
      &= -\frac{GM_1M_2}{r}
\end{aligned}
$$

I always make mistakes with signs in this.

I can't understand where you get the extra mass term in your derivation from.  But it's obvious from dimensional considerations that it must be wrong: $G$ has dimensions $l^3/(mt^2)$, so $GM_1M_2/r$ has dimensions $ml^2/t^2$, which are the dimensions of energy.

---

### Sign convention for Newton's law

As above, Newton's law of gravitation is

$$F = \mathbf{-}\frac{GM_1M_2}{r^2}$$

Why is there a $-$?.  The easiest way to think about this is to think in one dimension, where we have something like this:

[image: F and r]

The force, $F$ acts in the *opposite* direction to the separation, $r$, because gravity attracts things.  So in any consistent sign convention we'll get a $-$-sign in the expression for Newton's law of gravity: what it tells us is that the force is trying to pull things in the $-r$ direction or, in other words, towards each other.

Comment: You are completely correct about me mistaking force and acceleration, I've edited that now. However, where does the negative sign in Newton's Law come from? r^2 obviously isn't a unit with direction, so what exactly does the negative sign indicate? I guess, that's what my whole confusion boils down to. Thanks so much for the in-depth integral!

Comment: @Smiley1000: I've added a section which I hope makes sense of this.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a negative sign.

The gravitational potential energy $U$ of two masses $m$ and $M$ separated by a distance $r$ is given by

$$U=-G\frac{mM}{r}$$

As the objects get closer together, the gravitational potential energy **becomes more negative**, which is another way to say that it **decreases**. As the potential energy decreases, the kinetic energy increases in such a way that the total energy (kinetic + potential) of the system remains constant. What may be confusing you is that the potential energy can decrease to negative infinity - there's no "lowest potential energy" state of the system in this model.

If both masses are true point masses (meaning that they have zero size and infinite density), then you can extract an arbitrarily large amount of energy from the system by moving the masses arbitrarily close to one another. In reality, this doesn't ever happen, for a few reasons:

- Almost all known objects have finite sizes. The above formula only works when the separation $r$ is much greater than the size of the objects involved; if the two objects get close enough, the amount of potential energy extracted can only increase until the two objects are touching.
- For the *large* point masses that we know of (i.e. black holes), general relativity ensures that gravity works very differently close to the event horizon.  This means that the above formula only works when the separation $r$ is much greater than the radius of the event horizon of the black hole. The merger of two black holes is currently calculated numerically, and in every case, an enormous but finite amount of energy is released.
- For the *tiny* point masses that we know of (i.e. leptons), a theory of quantum gravity is needed to describe their interaction. Since we don't have any experimentally-supported theory of quantum gravity yet, it would be incorrect to assume that the above formula is valid in this case.

Comment: Your answer makes quite a lot of sense, but where does this equation come from? If my above derivation is correct, the total potential energy should be E_pot = 2\*G\*m*M/r. Where does my factor of 2 go and where does your factor of -1 come from? Did I assume something incorrect?

Comment: @Smiley1000 Your derivation is incorrect. See the accepted answer for the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Let the potential energy if the system be zero at infinity then gravitational potential energy of the system is given as$$E=\frac{-GMm}{r}$$ You have missed the negative sign in your answer which accounts for the error.When the system is released from rest when it is at a separation of $2r$ then kinetic energy of the system increases which comes at the cost of system's potential energy which is consistent with mechanical energy conservation law.

Comment: How does one derive this equation? What part of my derivation is incorrect?